# Ошибка в SQL, как решить?

Tags: sql

При переходе на некоторые страницы появляется такая ошибка, с чем она связана и как ее решить?

Вот скрин ошибки:

[image]

Comment: написано же, неизвестная база данных))

Comment: Пожалуйста, никогда не выкладывайте код или сообшения об ошибках картинками, только текстом. Из ответа я всё перенёс, можете его удалить.

Answer (score 0):

Связано с тем что база периодически бывает недоступна (если это повторяется на разных страницах с различным интервалом)
Если такая ошибка на определенных страницах - у тебя идет обращение к базе, которая не существует или неверный пароль / логин

База и лара у тебя на одном хостинге?

Я б посоветовал бы мидлварю сделать на проверку к подключению к БД, чтоб не ловить ошибки, а отписываться юзерам что что-то не так с подключением